# How do I wrap a sprite around a cube without GL_REPEAT?

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

I'm using OpenGL 3.2+. I created a cube VBO of 8 verticies (each vertex consists of 8 floats: x,y,z,r,g,b,s,t), an EBO to create the faces for that cube, and a VAO to tie it all together.

I have a sprite atlas consisting of hundreds of 16x16 sprites. I'm trying to get 1 sprite from that atlas to appear on all sides of the cube (any orientation is fine).

[image]

By tweaking the "s,t" parameters, I can get 4 of the 6 faces to work, but I can't seem to get the last 2 faces to show anything other than random garbage.

Do I need to modify my shader to perform some kind of custom UV wrapping on the atlas?

Comment: The most straight-forward (and also probably most efficient) way would be to use the proper number of vertices, which would be 24 in the case of a general cube.

Comment: @derhass A cube has [8 vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube); 24 doesn't sound "proper" but that's one possible way (though I question the efficiency) to make this work.

Comment: Well, you were asking explicitely for OpenGL, not math. In OpenGL, a vertex is an n-tuple of all attributes, not just the position, and if the value of some attribute differs, it follows that it can't be the same vertex. While it is true that you can get away with less than 24 vertices if you don't care about the orientation (and don't plan any lighting), 24 is still the usual vertex count of a cube, and it is not inefficient per-say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By tweaking the "s,t" parameters, I can get 4 of the 6 faces to work, but I can't seem to get the last 2 faces to show anything other than random garbage.

At least you have to use separate vertices and attributes, for 2 edges of the cube. This means you need at least 8+2*2=12 different sets of vertex attributes.

[image]

```
         x  y  z    u  v
0  :    -1  1  1    0  0
1  :     1  1  1    1  0
2  :    -1 -1  1    0  1
3  :     1 -1  1    1  1
4  :    -1 -1 -1    0  0
5  :     1 -1 -1    1  0
6  :    -1  1 -1    0  1 
7  :     1  1 -1    1  1
8  :    -1  1  1    1  1
9  :    -1  1 -1    1  0
10 :     1  1  1    0  1
11 :     1  1 -1    0  0
```

Note, the vertex attribute sets with the indices 0, 2, 4 and 6 have an identically u-coordinate of 0. And the vertex attribute sets with the indices 1, 3, 5 and 7 have an identically u-coordinate of 1.
If you want to wrap a texture to a quad you have to vary the u and the v coordinates. Because of that you have to add the separated vertex attribute sets 8, 9, 10 and 11.

**Note, if you want to add normal vectors which are perpendicular to the side planes of the cube, the you need 24 vertex attributes sets. 4 for each side of the cube.**