# Rotate layer Rubik's Cube

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, rubiks-cube

I'm programming a rubik cube in c with SDL and OpenGl. I have done all the implementation, except the rotation of a layer move (now if i press 'r' or 'f', for example, right or front layers change its colours). I don't really know how to implement the rotation of a layer.

Here is my render implementation which draws the cube.

Note: mov is 7 if i want to rotate clockwise right layer, 8 if i want to rotate left layer etc, **s is an array with the rgb color of each sticker of the cube

```
static void
Render(int mov, double **s)
{
    static float color[8][3] = {
        {1.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
        {0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };

    static float cube[56][3] = {
        // Cara 1
        {0.6, 0.6, 0.6},
        {0.6, 0.6, 0.2},
        {0.6, 0.6, -0.2},
        {0.6, 0.6, -0.6},
        {0.6, 0.2, -0.6},
        {0.6, -0.2, -0.6},
        {0.6, -0.6, -0.6},
        {0.6, -0.6, -0.2},
        {0.6, -0.6, 0.2},
        {0.6, -0.6, 0.6},
        {0.6, -0.2, 0.6},
        {0.6, 0.2, 0.6},
        {0.6, 0.2, 0.2},
        {0.6, 0.2, -0.2},
        {0.6, -0.2, -0.2},
        {0.6, -0.2, 0.2},

        // Cara 2
        {0.2, 0.6, 0.6},
        {-0.2, 0.6, 0.6},
        {-0.6, 0.6, 0.6},
        {-0.6, 0.6, 0.2},
        {-0.6, 0.6, -0.2},
        {-0.6, 0.6, -0.6},
        {-0.2, 0.6, -0.6},              // 22
        {0.2, 0.6, -0.6},
        {0.2, 0.6, -0.2},
        {0.2, 0.6, 0.2},
        {-0.2, 0.6, 0.2},
        {-0.2, 0.6, -0.2},              // 27

        // Cara 3
        {-0.6, 0.2, 0.6},
        {-0.6, 0.2, 0.2},
        {-0.6, 0.2, -0.2},
        {-0.6, 0.2, -0.6},
        {-0.6, -0.2, -0.6},
        {-0.6, -0.6, -0.6},             // 33
        {-0.6, -0.6, -0.2},
        {-0.6, -0.6, 0.2},
        {-0.6, -0.6, 0.6},
        {-0.6, -0.2, 0.6},
        {-0.6, -0.2, 0.2},
        {-0.6, -0.2, -0.2},             // 39

        // Cara 4
        {-0.2, -0.6, 0.6},
        {-0.2, -0.6, 0.2},
        {-0.2, -0.6, -0.2},
        {-0.2, -0.6, -0.6},
        {0.2, -0.6, -0.6},              // 44
        {0.2, -0.6, -0.2},
        {0.2, -0.6, 0.2},
        {0.2, -0.6, 0.6},               // 47

        // Cara 5
        {0.2, 0.2, 0.6},
        {0.2, -0.2, 0.6},
        {-0.2, -0.2, 0.6},
        {-0.2, 0.2, 0.6},

        // Cara 6
        {0.2, 0.2, -0.6},
        {0.2, -0.2, -0.6},
        {-0.2, -0.2, -0.6},
        {-0.2, 0.2, -0.6}

    };

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    // Cara 1

    glColor3f(s[2][0], s[2][1], s[2][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[8]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[9]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[10]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[15]);

    glColor3f(s[5][0], s[5][1], s[5][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[10]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[11]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[12]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[15]);

    glColor3f(s[8][0], s[8][1], s[8][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[0]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[1]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[12]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[11]);              // ST2

    glColor3f(s[1][0], s[1][1], s[1][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[7]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[8]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[15]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[14]);

    glColor3f(s[4][0], s[4][1], s[4][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[12]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[13]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[14]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[15]);

    glColor3f(s[7][0], s[7][1], s[7][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[1]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[13]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[12]);

    glColor3f(s[0][0], s[0][1], s[0][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[5]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[6]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[7]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[14]);

    glColor3f(s[3][0], s[3][1], s[3][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[4]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[5]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[14]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[13]);

    glColor3f(s[6][0], s[6][1], s[6][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[3]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[4]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[13]);

    // Cara 2
    glColor3f(s[11][0], s[11][1], s[11][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[0]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[1]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[25]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[16]);

    glColor3f(s[10][0], s[10][1], s[10][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[1]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[24]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[25]);

    glColor3f(s[9][0], s[9][1], s[9][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[3]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[23]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[24]);

    glColor3f(s[12][0], s[12][1], s[12][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[23]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[24]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[27]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[22]);

    glColor3f(s[15][0], s[15][1], s[15][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[22]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[27]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[20]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[21]);

    glColor3f(s[16][0], s[16][1], s[16][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[27]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[26]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[19]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[20]);

    glColor3f(s[17][0], s[17][1], s[17][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[26]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[17]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[18]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[19]);

    glColor3f(s[14][0], s[14][1], s[14][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[25]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[16]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[17]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[26]);

    glColor3f(s[13][0], s[13][1], s[13][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[24]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[25]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[26]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[27]);

    // Cara 3

    glColor3f(s[47][0], s[47][1], s[47][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[18]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[19]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[29]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[28]);

    glColor3f(s[46][0], s[46][1], s[46][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[19]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[20]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[30]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[29]);

    glColor3f(s[45][0], s[45][1], s[45][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[20]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[21]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[31]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[30]);

    glColor3f(s[48][0], s[48][1], s[48][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[31]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[30]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[39]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[32]);

    glColor3f(s[51][0], s[51][1], s[51][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[32]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[39]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[34]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[33]);

    glColor3f(s[52][0], s[52][1], s[52][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[39]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[38]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[35]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[34]);

    glColor3f(s[53][0], s[53][1], s[53][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[38]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[37]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[36]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[35]);

    glColor3f(s[50][0], s[50][1], s[50][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[29]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[28]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[37]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[38]);

    glColor3f(s[49][0], s[49][1], s[49][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[30]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[29]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[38]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[39]);

    // Cara 4
    glColor3f(s[33][0], s[33][1], s[33][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[35]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[36]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[40]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[41]);

    glColor3f(s[34][0], s[34][1], s[34][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[34]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[35]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[41]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[42]);

    glColor3f(s[35][0], s[35][1], s[35][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[33]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[34]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[42]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[43]);

    glColor3f(s[32][0], s[32][1], s[32][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[43]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[42]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[45]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[44]);

    glColor3f(s[29][0], s[29][1], s[29][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[44]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[45]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[7]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[6]);

    glColor3f(s[28][0], s[28][1], s[28][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[45]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[46]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[8]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[7]);

    glColor3f(s[27][0], s[27][1], s[27][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[46]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[47]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[9]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[8]);

    glColor3f(s[30][0], s[30][1], s[30][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[41]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[40]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[47]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[46]);

    glColor3f(s[31][0], s[31][1], s[31][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[42]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[41]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[46]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[45]);

    // Cara 5
    glColor3f(s[18][0], s[18][1], s[18][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[11]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[48]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[16]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[0]);

    glColor3f(s[21][0], s[21][1], s[21][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[48]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[51]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[17]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[16]);

    glColor3f(s[24][0], s[24][1], s[24][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[51]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[28]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[18]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[17]);

    glColor3f(s[25][0], s[25][1], s[25][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[50]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[37]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[28]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[51]);

    glColor3f(s[26][0], s[26][1], s[26][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[40]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[36]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[37]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[50]);

    glColor3f(s[23][0], s[23][1], s[23][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[47]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[40]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[50]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[49]);

    glColor3f(s[20][0], s[20][1], s[20][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[9]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[47]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[49]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[10]);

    glColor3f(s[19][0], s[19][1], s[19][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[10]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[49]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[48]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[11]);

    glColor3f(s[22][0], s[22][1], s[22][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[51]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[50]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[49]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[48]);

    // Cara 6
    glColor3f(s[36][0], s[36][1], s[36][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[44]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[6]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[5]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[53]);

    glColor3f(s[39][0], s[39][1], s[39][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[43]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[44]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[53]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[54]);

    glColor3f(s[42][0], s[42][1], s[42][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[33]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[43]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[54]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[32]);

    glColor3f(s[43][0], s[43][1], s[43][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[32]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[54]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[55]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[31]);

    glColor3f(s[44][0], s[44][1], s[44][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[31]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[55]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[22]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[21]);

    glColor3f(s[41][0], s[41][1], s[41][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[55]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[52]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[23]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[22]);

    glColor3f(s[38][0], s[38][1], s[38][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[52]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[4]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[3]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[23]);

    glColor3f(s[37][0], s[37][1], s[37][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[53]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[5]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[4]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[52]);

    glColor3f(s[40][0], s[40][1], s[40][2]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[53]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[54]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[55]);
    glVertex3fv(cube[52]);

    glEnd();

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    if (mov == 1) {
        glRotatef(2.0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (mov == 2) {
        glRotatef(2.0, 1.0, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (mov == 3) {
        glRotatef(2.0, 0, 1.0, 0);
    }
    else if (mov == 4) {
        glRotatef(2.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    }
    else
        glRotatef(1.0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of hard-coded values and repeated code here for what's essentially 6 faces divided into 9 quads.  It's no wonder you're having difficulty doing anything with it.

Comment: Please update your question title to `Need help to implement the rotation of a rubiks layer`, Then share code snippet and Makefile to help with reproducing the error. I am marking the ticket as needs improvement, please edit and add the details.

Comment: you need to change the internal representation of your cube from hard coded into something variable ... also [using tables+`for` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619921/2521214) will simplify your code considerably... For the Rubik's cube layer rotations see: [Quaternion rotation does not work as excepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024016/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

Rotation is going to be too hard to keep track of unless you refactor your code into some sort of "Block" class, whereby a 3x3 array of blocks will make your Rubik's cube. each block will be exactly the same: white bottom, yellow top, blue left, etc... and when stacked 3x3 on screen will hide the other faces. This is a much easier simplification than keeping track of an array of faces to an array of colors.

Then you will want to make a clear distinction between the code model of your Rubik's cube, and the drawn model of your Rubik's cube. This is important in being able to apply multiply rotations successively.

So in code you will want to have a model of your cube. a 3x3 array is easy, where each row is a face. Then looking at a face, for example:

1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9

you will want access to a function that rotates this face (look at something that does the equivalent as numpy.rot90), such that when rotated around the axis that is pointing out of the screen, will produce:

3  6  9

2  5  8

1  4  7

But be careful here. This only changed the layout of the object in memory and hasn't done anything to the drawn model on screen. So you will need to apply the corresponding rotation in OpenGL. After this is done, your code model will now match the drawn model, and you can perform as many successive rotations as you want.